# How to disable password login through ssh for root, while allowing certificate based login

Tags: ssh, docker, root

I am setting up a docker container, into which I will be SSH'ing remotely. I would like to disable password login for root, and only allow certificate based authentication. Setting `PermitRootLogin without-password` in /etc/ssh/ssh_config seems to have no effect.

Any thoughts?

Comment: System configuration is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you made modification to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` when you meant to add them to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (notice the added `d`)? The `PermitRootLogin` option is for the SSH daemon while the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` is default for the client.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to setup ssh shared keys... (That's what I've done).
here a quick tutorial:
[http://hocuspokus.net/2008/01/ssh-shared-key-setup-ssh-logins-without-passwords/][1]

I hope this + the /etc/ssh/ssh_config you've changed, will help.